# While loop with true condition in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Will the below 'while' loop run infinitely?

```
 while (true)

          try {
                year = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Enter valid Year");
                System.out.print("try Again:-");

            }
```

Comment: notice the `break` statement

Comment: Only if every input is invalid.

Comment: remove the `break` statement, then it will be infinitive

Comment: Nope, it is not. Unless you infinitely parse invalid integer :)

Answer (score 2):

Due to the `break`, it will not.

Answer (score 1):

This loop will break when the input is a proper integer.

Answer (score 1):

Your while will break if you parse correctly the variable year,
However I think that a better practice is to use a boolean variable to verify when should you stop the while operation.

```
while(!isYearInCorrectFormat) {
 ...
}
```